# Why does my code say that 90 was repeated 6 times, instead of 5?

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, for-loop, max

The problem I am working on is called "Birthday Cake Candles" from HackerRank.

Basically, the program takes in inputs and then outputs the number of times the largest input was inputted.

For example, if the input could be:

4

3 2 1 3

4 would be the number of elements in the array.
3 2 1 3 would be the elements in the array.

The output would be 2, since 3 (the largest) repeats 2 times.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    long long num;
    cin >> num;
    
    long long arr[num];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    
    long long qwer{};
    
    //find the largest value
    for (int i = 1; i<num; i++) {
        if (arr[0] < arr[i]) {
            arr[0] = arr[i];
            if (arr[0] == arr[i]) {
                arr[0] = arr[i];
            }
        }
        qwer = arr[0];
    }

    
    long long howmany = 0;
    
    //find how many times the largest value is repeated
    for (int i = 0; i<num; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == qwer) {
            howmany += 1;
        }
    }
    
    cout << howmany;
    
    return 0;
}
```

My code gives the correct output for the test case mentioned above. However, for the following test cases, the output is incorrect:

10

18 90 90 13 90 75 90 8 90 43

For this test case, my program outputted 6, instead of 5.

10

44 53 31 27 77 60 66 77 26 36

For this test case, my program outputted 3, instead of 2.

What is wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code isn't really valid C++, as C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: As for your problem, that's usually solved with something that isn't taught at competition sites (which aren't teaching or learning resources): ***Debugging***. With a *debugger* you can step through the code statement by statement, while monitoring variables and see how they change.

Comment: Do you know [std::max_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) and [std::count](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count). You can replace your second loop with `max_element` and the third loop with `count`. A much better approach is to avoid arrays. Don't store the values. Evaluate the input while you read it and count if it's the maximum value.

Comment: @holz Your code sets arr[0] equal to the maximum value and this element is countered though initially it did not contain the maximum value.

Comment: Hint: you should not modify the array.

Comment: Unrelated, but this part is a bit silly: `arr[0] = arr[i]; if (arr[0] == arr[i]) { arr[0] = arr[i]; }` (you're first assigning `arr[0] = arr[i]`, then checking if `arr[0] == arr[i]` which will always be true because you just assigned one to another, and then do `arr[0] = arr[i]` again which does nothing because a) you've already done that and b) even if you hadn't you just checked that they're equal so assigning one to another doesn't change anything.)

Comment: You don't need an array.  You can do this as a *running maxima*.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that your "find largest value" loop replaces the first element of your array with the highest value found. When you loop back through the array in your "find how many times" loop, you have an additional instance of the high value thus getting back the 6 instead of 5.

Your array when you input:
18 90 90 13 90 75 90 8 90 43

Your array when after the "find largest value" loop has completed:
**90** 90 90 13 90 75 90 8 90 43

The reason this worked on your first example is because the highest value is the first element. Therefore, you are not replacing the first element with anything and creating an additional instance in your array. If you were to try an array of 10 with the highest value first, you would get the correct number outputted.

Also, you could change the loop to this:

```
    qwer = arr[0];

    //find the largest value
    for (int i = 1; i<num; i++) {
        if (qwer < arr[i]) {
            qwer = arr[i];
        }
    }
```

This would remove the problem that you are seeing with the inconsistency between your examples.

Answer (score 1):

There are many better ways to do the same, as another answers here.

But focusing on answer your question:

I think your mistake is store the largest number in the first position of your array.

```
if (arr[0] < arr[i]) {
            arr[0] = arr[i];
```

Look this case test:
10

18 90 90 13 90 75 90 8 90 43

Here, you replaced the first iten, 18, with 90. So, you got 6 instead of 5 on your last loop.

Can you try to replace the above commented piece of code with this bellow?

```
if (arr[0] < arr[i]) {
            qwer  = arr[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop wasting memory. You don't need to store all the values. Read the input. Check if it's the current max number or if it's a new max number. Change `count`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    
    std::int64_t num;
    std::cin >> num;
    
    std::int64_t count = 0;
    std::int64_t maxNumber = std::numeric_limits<std::int64_t>::min();
    
    for (std::int64_t i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        std::int64_t input;
        std::cin >> input;
        if (input > maxNumber) {
            maxNumber = input;
            count = 1;
        } else if (input == maxNumber) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    
    std::cout << count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a running maxima, without using arrays:

```
int total = 0;
std::cin >> total;
int maxima;
int count = 1;
std::cin >> maxima; // Use first value as the maxima.
--total;
for (int i = 0; i < total; ++i)
{
  int value;
  std::cin >> value;
  if (value == maxima)
  {
    ++count;
  }
  else
  {
    if (value > maxima)
    {
      maxima = value;
      count = 1;
    }
  }
}
std::cout << "Largest value: " << maxima << ", quantity: " << count << std::endl;
```

The above code maintains the largest value and the quantity of occurrences of the largest value.  If a new maximum value is read, the count is reset to one.

Answer (score 0):

For starters variable length arrays

```
long long num;
cin >> num;

long long arr[num];
//...
```

is not a standard C++ feature.

Secondly for this task there is no need to create an array to store entered values because what you need is to count how frequently the maximum value is encountered. Moreover creating a big array with automatic storage duration can result in stack overflow.

In this for loop

```
for (int i = 1; i<num; i++) {
    if (arr[0] < arr[i]) {
        arr[0] = arr[i];
        if (arr[0] == arr[i]) {
            arr[0] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    qwer = arr[0];
}
```

this if statement

```
        if (arr[0] == arr[i]) {
            arr[0] = arr[i];
        }
```

is redundant and in fact does nothing.

Pay attention to that the element arr[0] is overwritten by the current maximum value though initially it might not contain such a value.

In this for loop

```
//find how many times the largest value is repeated
for (int i = 0; i<num; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == qwer) {
        howmany += 1;
    }
}
```

you can count one more element with the maximum value because the element arr[0] was set equal to the maximum value and it is counted.

The program can look simpler using only one loop.

Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    size_t n = 0;
    
    std::cin >> n;
    
    size_t howmany = 0;
    long long int max;
    long long int value;
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n && std::cin >> value; i++ )
    {
        
        if ( i == 0 || max < value )
        {
            max = value;
            howmany = 1;
        }
        else if ( not ( value  < max ) )
        {
            ++howmany;
        }
    }
    
    std::cout << howmany << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

If to enter the sequence

```
10
18 90 90 13 90 75 90 8 90 43
```

then the output will be

```
5
```